# How to use mod_proxy to proxy one call to multiple endpoints?

Tags: apache-2.2, git, mod-proxy, jenkins

We are in the process of migrating jobs from an old Jenkins CI server to a newly built one.  In the meantime most of the repositories on our Git server (Stash) are configured to invoke a git-hook on the old server using a DNS alias, "jenkins."  Once the migration is done, we will simply update the alias to point to the new box.  This is to avoid the need to update hundreds of git-hooks on the Stash server.

In the mean time all the git-hook calls are going to go to the old box, even for jobs that have already been migrated to the new box.

We are already using Apache httpd in front of both boxes for SSL termination among other things.  It occurred to me that it would be great if we could configure the proxy in front of the old box to forward the incoming git-hook calls (simple HTTP Gets to a specific endpoint) to go to both the old and new Jenkins servers at the same time.  The response from the old server would be the one returned to the caller and the response from the new server ignored.  (The response isn't used for anything in either case.)

It there a way to set this up?